# Android find contact by name unrelated to Charcase

Tags: java, android, char, call, contacts

I want to make a code which will find a contact and call him either if the contact is equals to the search or if it is in low case or up case 
This is the code i currently use

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
        "DISPLAY_NAME = '" + "contactname" + "'", null, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    String contactId =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        String number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        int type = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
        switch (type) {
            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+number));
                startActivity(callIntent);
                break;
        }
    }
    phones.close();
}

cursor.close();
```

Right now the code find the contact only if it saved exactly the way the search was entered, i want it to find the contact unrelated to its character case

Answer (score 1):

You can use methos of Java `equalsIgnoreCase()` for comparing String after retrival of contact names.

```
str1.equalsIgnoreCase(str2);
```

And if you are asking for Query to do this work  try this

```
UPPER(contactName)=UPPER(contactSearchText)
```

or

```
LOWER(contactName)=LOWER(contactSearchText)
```

Comment: I didn't understand where in the code should i put "str1.equalsIgnoreCase(str2);"?

Comment: Hi non of this worked, please do you have any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to fix it myself

```
String name = "contact_name_to_search_for"
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
        null,"DISPLAY_NAME" + " LIKE '%"+name+"%'", null,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LAST_TIME_CONTACTED + " DESC");
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    String contactId =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)).toLowerCase();
    Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId.toLowerCase(), null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        String number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        int type = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
        switch (type) {
            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), number+" Home number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                break;
            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), number+" Mobile number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                break;
            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), number+" Work number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                break;
        }
    }
    phones.close();
}
cursor.close();
```